# python using concurrent.futures library for SHA256 + salt encryption

Tags: python, concurrency

I have the encryption function that is constantly computing new derived hashes with a constant salt value and varying pwd field that is a string.

```
def EncyptPrimary(salt, pwd):
dkey = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', pwd, salt, 100000, dklen=32)
return str(binascii.b2a_hex(dkey))
```

I would like to run this function across multiple CPUs with the concurrent.futures library.

all of the documentation for executor.map() is confusing how they get it to work. I tried.

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(EncyptPrimary(salt, pwd))
```

but it throws an error saying, cannot use type generator.